CMake FetchContent: How to not use the extracted cmake file now that FetchContent_Populate is deprecated?
After upgrading to CMake 3.30, this fine wrapper function …
function(fetch_and_extract_archive dst_name url checksum)
    cmake_parse_arguments(ARG "POPULATE_ONLY" "" "" "${ARGN}")
    FetchContent_Declare("${dst_name}" URL ${url} URL_HASH "${checksum}")
    if(ARG_POPULATE_ONLY)
        if(NOT ${dst_name}_POPULATED)
            FetchContent_Populate(${dst_name})
        endif()
    else()
        FetchContent_MakeAvailable(${dst_name})
    endif()
    set("${dst_name}_SOURCE_DIR" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/${dst_name}-src" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

… turned into this build error:
CMake Error (dev) at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1953 (message):
  Calling FetchContent_Populate() is deprecated, call
  FetchContent_MakeAvailable() instead.  Policy CMP0169 can be
  set to OLD to allow FetchContent_Populate() to be called
  directly for now, but the ability to call it with declared details will be
  removed completely in a future version.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  …
This error is for project developers. Use -Wno-error=dev to suppress it.

Obviously, I'm trying to not use the extracted CMakeLists.txt when ARG_POPULATE_ONLY is set, which is why I'm not simply using MakeAvailable.

From documentation, only the single-argument version of FetchContent_Populate is actually deprecated; the long form takes arguments similar to FetchContent_Declare.
Unfortunately, naively substituting these does not do the same. The directories are off.

FetchContent_MakeAvailable performs add_subdirectory call only when source directory of the fetched project actually contains CMakeLists.txt. If your fetched project contains top-level CMakeLists.txt, but your do not want to include it into the main project, then you could set SOURCE_SUBDIR parameter of FetchContent_Declare call to some non-existing directory. That way you will be able to use regular FetchContent_MakeAvailable for your purposes. This approach is taken from here: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/fetchcontent-a-directory-but-add-a-subdirectory/8603/15
